# Undefined value in Javascript response after doing a calculation

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return a value from a calculation that I have but I am getting an undefined value. Here is my code.

```js
var salaryScales = [{"age":18,"increase":0.135},
                {"age":19,"increase":0.135},
                {"age":20,"increase":0.135},
                {"age":21,"increase":0.126},
                {"age":22,"increase":0.117},
                {"age":23,"increase":0.108},
                {"age":24,"increase":0.099},
                {"age":25,"increase":0.090},
                {"age":26,"increase":0.083},
                {"age":27,"increase":0.076},
                {"age":28,"increase":0.069},
                {"age":29,"increase":0.062},
                {"age":30,"increase":0.055},
                {"age":31,"increase":0.050},
                {"age":32,"increase":0.045},
                {"age":33,"increase":0.043},
                {"age":34,"increase":0.041},
                {"age":35,"increase":0.039},
                {"age":36,"increase":0.037},
                {"age":37,"increase":0.035},
                {"age":38,"increase":0.033},
                {"age":39,"increase":0.031},
                {"age":40,"increase":0.029},
                {"age":41,"increase":0.027},
                {"age":42,"increase":0.025},
                {"age":43,"increase":0.023},
                {"age":44,"increase":0.021},
                {"age":45,"increase":0.019},
                {"age":46,"increase":0.017},
                {"age":47,"increase":0.015},
                {"age":48,"increase":0.015},
                {"age":49,"increase":0.015},
                {"age":50,"increase":0.015},
                {"age":51,"increase":0.015},
                {"age":52,"increase":0.015},
                {"age":53,"increase":0.015},
                {"age":54,"increase":0.015},
                {"age":55,"increase":0.015},
                {"age":56,"increase":0.015},
                {"age":57,"increase":0.015},
                {"age":58,"increase":0.015},
                {"age":59,"increase":0.015},
                {"age":60,"increase":0.015},
                {"age":61,"increase":0.015},
                {"age":62,"increase":0.015},
                {"age":63,"increase":0.015},
                {"age":64,"increase":0.015},
                {"age":65,"increase":0.015}];

function test() {
  var age = 35;
  var retAge = 65;
  var standard = 47;
  var inflation = 0.055;
  var returnPercentage = 0.04;
  var cumulativeInflation = 1 + inflation;
  var pensionableSalary = 0.73;
  var contributionPercentage = 0.15;
  var startFundCredit = 100000;
  var totalSalary = 360000;
  var endFundCredit = 0;
  var realFundCredit = 0;
  var list = [];



  for (var i = 0; i <= standard; i++) {
    var year = i;
    var ageIn = age;
    var yearsToRetirement = retAge - age;
    var contributions = totalSalary * pensionableSalary * contributionPercentage;
    endFundCredit = (startFundCredit * (1 + (returnPercentage + inflation))) + (contributions * Math.pow((1 + (returnPercentage + inflation)), 0.5));
    realFundCredit = endFundCredit / cumulativeInflation;

    list.push({
      'year': year,
      'age': age,
      'yearsToRetirement': yearsToRetirement,
      'cumulativeInflation': cumulativeInflation,
      'startFundCredit': startFundCredit,
      'totalSalary': totalSalary,
      'contributions': contributions,
      'endFundCredit': endFundCredit,
      'realFundCredit': realFundCredit
    });
    cumulativeInflation = cumulativeInflation * (1 + inflation);
    startFundCredit = endFundCredit;
    var salaryScale = getSalaryScale(ageIn);
    totalSalary = totalSalary * (1 + inflation + salaryScale); //salary scales
    age++;
  }
}


function getSalaryScale(ageIn) {
  var result = salaryScales.filter(function(item) {
    return item.age === ageIn
  });
  return result[0].increase;
}

test();
```

I am trying to get the value of result[0].increase but am stuck, Any ideas?

Comment: `function test()` is not returning, which is why you are getting undefined.

Comment: also, you pass `35` to `getSalaryScale` but your `salaryScales` only includes 18, 19 and 20

Comment: @Archie - the error is `result[0]` is undefined - because `salaryScales` doesn't include a scale for the age passed in, 35

Comment: @JaromandaX I have altered it

Comment: *Aside note*: as you want the first index `result[0].increase`, I recommend using the function `Array.prototype.find`.

Comment: I have made a stackbliz https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-klknr3

Comment: OK, so now it works for age 35, 36, 37 ... then fails at 38, because ... well, do I have to say it?

Comment: @JaromandaX please check now

Comment: and now it works until 65, then fails at 66 ... can you see a pattern developing? it always fails when you call the function with an age that doesn't exist in the "table"

Comment: @JaromandaX this is the final list, there won't be any more ages

Comment: then do range checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You ideas of using **ES6** in order to get the salaryScale is good but the problem is that if you pass an age that does not exist in the array, you will have an error.

Instead, I advice you to use `Array.prototype.find` method like this:

```js
var salaryScales = [{"age":18,"increase":0.135},
                    {"age":19,"increase":0.135},
                    {"age":20,"increase":0.135}];

function getSalaryScale(ageIn){
  var result = salaryScales.find(item => item.age === ageIn);
  return result === undefined ? undefined : result.increase;
}

console.log(getSalaryScale(18)); // 0.135
console.log(getSalaryScale(12)); // undefined
```

Or you can even throw an error if you don't want to return undefined or whatever you want

Comment: Even if you add more salaryScale, one can just say **getSalarayScale(210)** and it will crash your app. By doing the way above, you will have a *full control* on the result of finding if it exists an age of 210.

Comment: But why would `console.log(result[0].increase);` be undefined? if I have it in the getSalaryScale function?

Comment: As I said, I just put **undefined** to let you know that can event put a* default value* for all the cases where there is not an age. So it is up to you now.
And about `console.log()` it is just to show what would happen if you execute the function.

Answer (score -1):

result will return as a object , u didn't get array so u can not access result[0] can u please consol result so we can check what exactly comes in result

Answer (score -1):

You should be handling the scenario when the age is not is part of salaryScales, in your code except (18, 19 and 20), all other ages you will see this error